# Remove a drawn NSRect or other drawn object

Tags: objective-c, rect, nsbezierpath

How do I remove a drawn NSRect or other object other than drawing another rect over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you drew the rect in `drawRect:`, all you need to do would be to exclude the rect from the list of objects to be drawn and call `[view setNeedsDisplayInRect:theRect]`. `theRect` here would be the `CGRect` equivalent.